# How can write XForms that performs a check in the XML data by invoking XQuery?

Tags: xml, orbeon, xforms

I am new to the XForms technology, and I am finding difficult to achieve the following functionality.

My objective is: upon clicking a link or button to edit a resource, typically XML, some checking (by invoking an XQuery for example, checking an element within the resource) has to happen, and based on the return value of the XQuery I need to throw an error dialog or edit window.

It would be great if someone guides me through in achieving the above functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You will get more useful answer here if you bring a more specific issue to the table, describe your attempt to implement it, if possible including minimal but working code, and present where exactly it fails.

But I understand that this is hard to do if you're new to the XForms technology. So I would recommend you start by going through the [Orbeon XForms Tutorial](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/orbeon-forms-xforms-tutorial). You should learn there all the ingredients you need to implement this. And of course, if you have any question along the way, feel free to post them on Stack Overflow.